# Wordpress custom loop if/else display

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have pieced together the following code but can't quite get it to work as I need it to.

I'm using Advanced Custom fields to add a PDF upload to my custom post type ('software_pdf' field) so it needs to look at all the posts for that custom post type and if there are no PDF's uploaded to anyone of them, display a message 'No Data Available.'

If there is a PDF attached to any of the posts, it needs to not show the message and instead list just the titles that have a PDF attached.

My issue is that it lists the titles with PDF's attached but it also still shows the 'No Data Available' message and I am stuck on how to resolve that. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$custom_loop = new WP_Query(array( 
  'paged' => $paged, 
  'post_type' => 'Products', 
  'cat' => 5,
  'posts_per_page' => 25,
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order'   => 'ASC',
));

if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) :

while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post();

$softwarepdf = get_field('software_pdf');

if (empty( $softwarepdf ) ) { ?>

<p class="nodata">No Data Available.</p>

<? }

else { ?>

<p class="productthumbtitle"><?php the_title(); ?></p>

PDF

<? }

endwhile;

wp_reset_query(); 
endif;
```

Comment: What happens if you remove "global $post;" ? I don't think that should be there.

Comment: Also the "else if( !empty( $.... " is not necessary. $softwarepdf is either empty or it's not, so there's no need to test both.

Comment: Thanks also for your replies, much appreciated. I have removed the two items above, it still works as it did before so they were not needed as you said - however it still does not show a message if there is no PDFs or display the post titles and no message of those with PDFs.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question? It makes it easier for others to contribute.

Comment: Sure, it's not much different other than your suggested changes

Answer (score 0):

Try **get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'software_pdf');** instead of **get_field('software_pdf');**

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately changing that means the message does not display if there are no PDFs and it now just lists all the titles regardless of if there is a PDF or not.

Comment: try get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'software_pdf', true);

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That now only returns the Posts where a PDF is attached which is what I need it to do, but unfortunately still displays the 'No Data Available.' message.

Comment: You use in that way? `$softwarepdf = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'software_pdf', true)

if (empty( $softwarepdf ) ) { ?>

<p class="nodata">No Data Available.</p>

<? }

else if (!empty( $softwarepdf ) ) { ?>

<p class="productthumbtitle"><?php the_title(); ?></p>

PDF

<? }`

Comment: If get_post_meta returns a value the if sould not enter in No Data Available

Comment: That's exactly how I have it and it still returns the No Data Available message unfortunately. I had wondered if it is because it finds some posts without PDFs and some with PDFs so both conditions are true so it returns both?

Comment: Just remove the No Data Available if. Just left the loop `if (!empty( $softwarepdf ) ) { ?>

<p class="productthumbtitle"><?php the_title(); ?></p>

PDF

<? }`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If I remove that then it will not show a message if there are no PDFs attached to any of the posts which is what it needs to do? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Sorry, but i understood that you dont want to show the message No Data Availabe. If the message appears is because you have posts without pdf. Check the value of pdf in posts.

Comment: Sorry, I perhaps have not been clear. If there are no PDFs attached it should show the message 'No Data Available'

If there IS a PDF the message needs to be hidden at the post title that has the PDF attached needs to be displayed in its place.

Currently it shows both the title of the post AND the message when there is a PDF attached which is wrong.